# Child widget send dynamic data

Tags: flutter

I have a two-page app. On-Page One I am showing an UUID which changes every 1 second. It is shown using listview. Once the user clicks on the list view it goes to the second page and shows the data on that card.

It should have been the changing UUID. but the data shown is static UUID. How I can pass the data changed on page 1 to page 2?

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid_util.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

List<EuropeanCountries> europeanCountries = [];

class EuropeanCountries {
  String myText;

  String myUuid;

  EuropeanCountries({
    this.myText,
    this.myUuid,
  });
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  int _perPage = 50;
  ScrollController _myScrollController = ScrollController();

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    const ThreeSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    this._counter++;
    europeanCountries.insert(
        0,
        EuropeanCountries(
          myText: this._counter.toString(),
        ));
    print(europeanCountries[0].myText);

    setState(() {});
  }

  void getMoreData() {
    print('adding More Product ');

    europeanCountries.add(EuropeanCountries(
      myText: this._counter.toString(),
    ));
    //europeanCountries.insert(0, EuropeanCountries(myText:this._counter.toString(), myButtonText: "", myColor: Colors.blue));
    setState(() {});
  }

  void generateUUID() async {
    var uuid = Uuid();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6000; i++) {
      await new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
      for (EuropeanCountries currCountry in europeanCountries) {
        currCountry.myUuid = uuid.v1();
      }
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    generateUUID();

    _myScrollController.addListener(() {
      double maxscroll = _myScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
      double currentScroll = _myScrollController.position.pixels;
      double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25;
      print("mac Scroll Controller - " + maxscroll.toString());
      print("Current  Scroll Controller - " + currentScroll.toString());
      print("delta  Scroll Controller - " + delta.toString());

      if ((maxscroll - currentScroll) < delta) {
        getMoreData();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _myListView(context),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {
    // backing data

    return Container(
      child: europeanCountries.length == 0
          ? Center(
              child: Text('No Product to Display'),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              controller: _myScrollController,
              itemCount: europeanCountries.length,
              reverse: false,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return myContainer(index: index);
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}

class myContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  const myContainer({Key key, this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _myContainerState createState() => _myContainerState();
}

class _myContainerState extends State<myContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 120,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue[700]),
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(europeanCountries[widget.index].myText),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Detail'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondRoute(
                          myCountry: europeanCountries[widget.index],
                        )),
              );
            },
            color: Colors.blue[700],
            textColor: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
            splashColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          Text(europeanCountries[widget.index].myUuid != null
              ? europeanCountries[widget.index].myUuid
              : 'Default')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  final EuropeanCountries myCountry;

  const SecondRoute({Key key, this.myCountry}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondRouteState createState() => _SecondRouteState();
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(SecondRoute oldWidget) {
    // TODO: implement didUpdateWidget
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text(widget.myCountry.myUuid != null
                    ? widget.myCountry.myText
                    : 'default'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              Center(
                child: Text(widget.myCountry.myUuid != null
                    ? widget.myCountry.myUuid
                    : 'default'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0l6J.jpg

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="VqRfcZY"><a href="//i.stack.imgur.com/u0l6J.jpg"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```